# How can I access the phantom object from CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, cookies, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using **CasperJS** for the first time and I want to add a cookie before loading a page. I'm using this code:

```
casper.test.setUp(function () {
  casper.echo('Cookies enabled?: ' + phantom.cookiesEnabled);
  phantom.addCookie({
    domain: '.localhost',
    name: 'sessionId',
    value: '12345abcd6789efg'
});
```

The problem seems to be with `phantom` in my code. I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor

How can I define `phantom`?

Answer (score 0):

**CasperJS** is built on top of **PhantomJS**, which means that your Casper environment is actually a PhantomJS environment with some extras...

The most basic script you could write to check your environment is the following:

```
console.log('PhantomJS version: ' + phantom.version.major + '.' + phantom.version.minor + '.' + phantom.version.patch);
phantom.exit();
```

Normally, you should be able to execute this script with `phantomjs` and `casperjs` commands. This will give you the same output as `phantomjs --version`.

In your script, you are using the **tester module** of CasperJS. But can we access the `phantom` object from there? Yes, of course!

```
casper.test.setUp(function () {
  console.log('PhantomJS version: ' + phantom.version.major + '.' + phantom.version.minor + '.' + phantom.version.patch);
});

casper.test.begin('Example', function (test) {
  casper.start('http://example.com');

  casper.then(function () {
    test.assertEquals(this.getTitle(), 'Example Domain');
  });

  casper.run(function () {
    test.done();
  });
});
```

This time you cannot use the `phantomjs` command and must use `casperjs test` instead. If you try to run this script, you should see the PhantomJS version before the test begins...